# No options when handle push notification SwiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I'm stuck with push notifications for my app. When I click on the notification when the app in foreground or in background, my code works fine with the function:

```
userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

But when the app is closed, the notification should trigger the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and add options. But the function is triggered but without options.

Here is my AppDelegate code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    @AppStorage("deviceToken") var deviceToken: String = ""
    @AppStorage("startWithNotification") var startWithNotification: Bool = false
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        startWithNotification = false
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        getNotificationSettings()
        
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            startWithNotification = true
            if(launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil){
                
            }
        }

        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        self.deviceToken = token
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // This function will be called when the app receive notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        // show the notification alert (banner), and with sound
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound, .badge])
    }
    
    // This function will be called right after user tap on the notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let application = UIApplication.shared

        if(application.applicationState == .active){
            print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
            
        }
        
        if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
        {
            print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

I add an AppStorage variable called "startWithNotification" that allow me to see on the first screen if the app start with an option or not. I set it to "True" on the line 13 but when the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function is triggered with options.

How can I resolve this issue?

Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace this:

```
// This function will be called when the app receive notification
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
    // show the notification alert (banner), and with sound
    completionHandler([.banner, .sound, .badge])
}
```

with this:

```
// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter
                            , willPresent notification: UNNotification
                            , withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I got the same issue when the app is closed. When I click on the notification in the NotificationCenter, the app is launched but nothing happen

Comment: When you click on the notification, this function will called: "func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
//do what you want if app is open from noti here
}